# Skip and Take in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have simple POCO classes:

```
public class Library
{
    [Key]
    public string LibraryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string BookId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And I have query, that returns libraries with already included books:

```
dbContext.Set<Library>.Include(x => x.Books);
```

I'm trying to skip 5 libraries and then take 10 of them:

```
await dbContext.Set<Library>.Include(x => x.Books).Skip(5).Take(10).ToListAsync();
```

The problem is, that when I'm trying to perform `Skip` and `Take` methods on this query, it returns libraries without included list of books.

How can I work with `Skip` and `Take`, with saving previously included entities?

Comment: What is the syntax you are using with `Skip` and `Take`? Since that is the issue, you should probably include those in the question.

Comment: @MattRowland edited the question, the problem is in these methods.

Comment: did you do use that in your connection (options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(connection).UseRowNumberForPaging());

Comment: It works, but doesn't it deprecated method, which is only for backwards compatability?

Comment: @BassamAlugili and if I use `UseRowNumberForPaging())`, `Skip` doesn't work with this.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure to follow the sequence of `OrderBy`, `Skip`, `Take`.
Usually you need to Order By first before use `Skip` and `Take` methods. (Even just changing the order of Take and Skip will impact the results) Try ordering by name like this way:

```
await dbContext.Set<Library>().Include(x => x.Books)
                              .OrderBy(x=>x.Name)
                              .Skip(5)
                              .Take(10)
                              .ToListAsync();
```

As far as I remember your query should be translated using  `OFFSET-FETCH` filter which requires an `ORDER BY` clause to exist.

Comment: I was reading there are some strange behaviors when you use include and then try to paginate later:https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4637. Just to know, what version of EF7 and SQL are you using?

Comment: I'm using `"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final"`

Comment: Try updating your EF library to rc2, maybe this issue was fixed in that version. Another comment that I saw in github was trying to call the `Include` after the pagination

Comment: `Include` after pagination doesn't work. Refer to your link to issue, that issue hasn't been fixed yet.