# Entity Framework Core - "The query processor ran out of internal resources" error only using EF, executing SQL server and get the results

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core 2.0, I have a set of queries to produce a result and it works flawlessly...

Except, for one specific query using EF `.where()` statements to build up the query, this and it throw's "The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan".

I've output the produces SQL and used SQL profiler - and executing the exact query in SQL Server (2016) takes less than one second, so I'm at a bit of a loss of how to diagnose this any further...

What would be the next steps to diagnose this error?

Comment: "What would be the next steps to diagnose this error?"  Create a simple, self-contained repro and post it in your question body.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks - I will when times allows, it's a fairly large project so it may be a reasonable job to distil it down to something sensible.

Comment: Exception stack trace might help.

Comment: If you have a "WHERE...IN ()" with lots of items in the "IN" part, it can cause this error. If that's your problem, you can fix it by joining to a table valued parameter instead of passing in a long a list of items. Usually it will be in the thousands of values before it causes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking your query up into smaller pieces, as [Microsoft suggests](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2012/03/13/8623-the-query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan/). Some possibilities might include taking vertical slices of your data using [Skip and Take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683555/skip-and-take-in-entity-framework-core) and handling them one at a time. Another option would be to bring your query in-memory with a .ToArray() call before your .Where(), so it won't be SQL handling that complex query, but your machine.