# How to implement pagination in webapi

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, pagination, entity-framework-core

How to implement pagination in webapi dotnet core ?

I tried using Skip / take , however skip / take works when there is only 1 table involved. In my case , I have to join few tables then implement pagination.

```
var searchList = _context.Table1
 .Include(b => b.Table2)
 .Include(c => c.Table3)
 .Include(c => c.Table4)
 .Include(c => c.Table5)
 .Include(c => c.Table6)                
.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize)            
.ToList();
```

What would be the better approach to implement pagination when there are multiple tables involved ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip and Take in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37683555/skip-and-take-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: I see that the link provided suggested me to use OrderBy before using Skip / Take which I did. However it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which EF Core version?

Comment: I am using 3.1.14 core version

Comment: So you want to apply pagination to Table2, Table3, etc.?? Do you know that `Include` is not `join` but instruction to load related entities. How it is implemented in EF it is another discussion. But never treat `Include` as JOIN.

Comment: Yes , I agree Include is not Join. Its just that all my tables are related with parent - child relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) MSDN doc you can use Filtered Include with Where clause in **.NET 5** SDK and later versions. and this operations supported in Include Where clause in .NET 5 and later versions :

- Where
- OrderBy(Descending)
- ThenBy(Descending)
- Skip
- Take

and your query can be like this:

```
var query = _context.Table1
      .Include(b => b.Table2.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))             
      .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
      .Take(pageSize)  
      .ToList();
```

Comment: What if I have multiple tables , in that case do I need to apply take / skip for all the tables ?

 var query = _context.Table1
      .Include(b => b.Table2.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))         
   .Include(b => b.Table3.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))    
   .Include(b => b.Table4.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))    
   .Include(b => b.Table5.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize))   
      .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
      .Take(pageSize)  
      .ToList();

Comment: Yes you should set all paginations on each table in it's Include() query.